# Android app: If I change the code (and save it), when I run it, the app isn't changed at all

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I know this question sounds very silly and basic, but basically, I'm creating an app using the Google Maps API, I had a custom marker showing up, then I tried to get geocoding to work, but I was having trouble so I decided to get rid of that section of the code and start again, but now the marker isn't showing up.

I realised however, that no matter how much I change the code, when I run the app, it isn't changing at all. I've tried uninstalling it and re-installing it, closing Eclipse and reopening it and of course I've tried to Google it but I haven't found anything.

Here is the code for my MainActivity (my only activity at the moment):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    LatLng ireland = new LatLng(53.0000, -8.0000);
    LatLng microsoftLatLng = new LatLng(53.276863, -6.211802);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ireland, 6));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(microsoftLatLng)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green_briefcase_icon)));      
  }  
}
```

I don't think the issue is to do with my code, I think it may be an issue with Eclipse but I don't understand why it's happening.

When I run the app, it is focused on Ireland at the desired zoom level (6) and has the GPS location button, but regardless of what latitude and longitude I put in, or if I get rid of "map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)", when I run it again (even if I've uninstalled it first), or even if I get rid of all of that code all together and just set the content view, it still is showing Ireland at that zoom level and has the GPS location button but no marker (but I had this exact code working perfectly before).

Here is my layout file:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mapsexample"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="16"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <activity
                android:name="com.example.mapsexample.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyBRsyLfnebJbNfteS2gcTYbTa7K2qREFm4" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: When this happens, usually Project->Clean will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a new project, copy over the code and create a new API key for that project, and everything is working perfectly again, the changes I make are seen when I run the app so all is good. I have no idea what the issue was but I hope it doesn't happen with the new app! Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps because you're moving the camera to the 'ireland' LatLng object?

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ireland, 6));
```

I believe if you want the current location, you gotta use the location service and ask for your current location, something like this

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

//ask via gps
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
        myLocationListener);

//ask via the network providers
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
        0, myLocationListener);
```

since the location will come asynchronously, you will have to implement a LocationListener, meaning implementing a:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

in there you want to move the camera to that location that changed to.

Something along those lines.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue as I had it working earlier with this code, what I want it to do when it runs it to move to the 'ireland' LatLng object, but have a marker at the 'microsoftLatLng' LatLng object and then move to the user's current location when the GPS button is clicked, I had all of that working, but now it's just not showing the marker anymore. The issue is that the app isn't changing when I change the code, regardless of what I change the code to, not with the code itself which I find odd.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure there are no errors in your resource files, as this will prevent `R.java` from getting regenerated. Then clean you entire project using `Project -> Clean...` as suggested. Also, I assume you have `Project -> Build Automatically` turned on, correct?

Comment: I can't see any errors in my resource files, I cleaned it, but now I'm getting an error "Could not find MapsExample.apk!", when I try to run it, and yes I have it set to build automatically.

Comment: So looks like since you cleaned it, it removed the previously successful build from `bin/`, so that's why it can't find it anymore. Any way you can post more code (layouts, Manifest) or pictures and we can see what else the culprit might be?

Comment: I put the layout and manifest file up now, in case they're causing a problem.

Comment: Have you changed/updated any build tools, Eclipse version, SDK you're compiling against? Any changes to the external dependencies for Google Play Services? Those are compiling ok?

Comment: I didn't knowingly change any of those things but I must have done something accidentally, I started a new project and copied the code over and everything is fine now, I still don't know what it was I changed but thanks for your advice.